# c++ error passing ‘const std::vector<Nodo>’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers

Tags: c++, bucles, iteradores

estoy implementando un algoritmo de búsqueda de camino mínimo, y me salen varios errores que no entiendo:

```
set< vector<Nodo>>&::iterator it;    

for(it=nodos_visitados.begin(); it!=nodos_visitados.end();it++){
  for(int i=(*it);i<(*it).size();i++){
    os<< " Nodo  con puntos " << (*it)[i].get_x() << " y "<< (*it)[i].get_y()<< "  con coste "<< (*it)[i].get_coste()<<endl; //para ningun operador se pone el punto
   }
 }
```

Obtengo varios errores:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
         set< vector<Nodo>>&::iterator it;
                         ^~
car.cpp:197:39: error: missing template arguments before ‘it’
         set< vector<Nodo>>&::iterator it;
                                       ^~
car.cpp:200:13: error: ‘it’ was not declared in this scope
         for(it=nodos_visitados.begin(); it!=nodos_visitados.end();it++){
```

Estoy aprendiendo C++, mi principal problema es que escribo código e intento mirar ejemplos que me sirvan de referencia, trato de escribir poco código y compilar, pero se me va mucho tiempo depurando código. Gracias

Comment: El título no tiene nada que ver ni con el código ni con los errores que muestras, deberías plantearte el cambiarlo.

Answer (score 1):

### C++98

En C++98, al trabajar con plantillas anidadas, **no es legal** dejar los cierres de las mismas juntos:

```
set< vector<Nodo>> variable;
//              ~~
```

Ya que esa secuencia se confunde con el operador de extracción:

```
std::cout >> a;
```

De tal forma que hay que dejar, al menos, un espacio entre un cierre de plantilla y el siguiente:

```
std::set<std::vector<Nodo> > nodos_visitados;
//                       ~~~
```

Adicionalmente el iterador está mal declarado. El iterador es un objeto dependiente de la clase `std::set` y, en consecuencia, le da absolutamente igual si el contenedor lo estás usando por valor, por referencia o mediante punteros... la declaración del iterador va a ser **siempre la misma**.

Esto quiere decir que el `&` en la declaración del iterador sobra:

```
std::set<std::vector<Nodo> >::iterator it = nodos_visitados.begin();
```

Esta línea compila perfectamente tanto si `nodos_visitados` es una variable al uso o una referencia:

```
std::set<std::vector<Nodo> >   por_valor;
std::set<std::vector<Nodo> > & referencia = &por_valor;

std::set<std::vector<Nodo> >::iterator it;
it = por_valor.begin();  // OK
it = referencia.begin(); // OK
```

Lo único que cambia en el caso de punteros es que tenemos que usar el operador de indirección `->` en vez de `.`:

```
std::set<std::vector<Nodo> > * punero = &por_valor;
it = por_valor->begin();
```

Pues bien, este iterador va a recorrer el `set`, dándonos acceso a su contenido. El contenido del `set` son vectores, luego `*it` nos va a devolver **un vector**. Esto implica que el segundo bucle está mal:

```
for(int i=(*it);i<(*it).size();i++)
```

No podemos convertir un `std::vector<Nodo>` en `int`. Quizás lo que tu intentabas era esto:

```
for(int i=0;i<(*it).size();i++)
```

Aunque, siendo estrictos, el método `size` no devuelve un entero sino `size_t`, un alias que en 32 bits suele equivaler a `unsigned int` y, en 64 bits, a `unsigned long long`. Para evitar *warnings* tontos y, ocasionalmente, un comportamiento errático, es recomendable usar los tipos correctos:

```
for(size_t i=0; i<it->size(); ++i)
```

Claro que también podemos seguir tirando por la vía de los iteradores:

```
std::vector<Nodo>::const_iterator it2;
for( it2 = it->begin(); it2 != it->end(); ++it2 )
{
  Nodo const& nodo = *it2;
  // ...
}
```

### C++11

C++11 trae algunas novedades que conviene saber.

La primera es que ya no es necesario separar los cierres de las plantillas. Los compiladores conformes a este estándar ya son capaces de distinguir los casos antes comentados, luego `nodos_visitados` puede declararse sin espacios:

```
std::set<std::vector<Nodo>> nodos_visitados;
```

Y lo mismo para el iterdor:

```
std::set<std::vector<Nodo>>::iterator it;
```

Ahora bien, C++11 también incorpora `auto`. Un mecanismo que delega la deducción del tipo de variable al compilador.

Así, en la siguiente línea:

```
auto it = nodos_visitados.begin();
```

`it`, dependiendo de si `nodos_visitados` es constante o no, podrá ser del tipo:

- `std::set<std::vector<Nodo>>::iterator`: `nodos_visitados` **no** es constante
- `std::set<std::vector<Nodo>>::const_iterator`: `nodos_visitados` **es** constante

Y además añade menos basura al código.

Incorporando este cambio los bucles quedan más legibles:

```
for(auto it=nodos_visitados.begin(); it!=nodos_visitados.end();it++)
{
  for(auto it2 = it->begin(); it2 != it->end(); ++it2)
  {
    os << " Nodo  con puntos "
       << it2->get_x()
       << " y "
       << it2->get_y()
       << "  con coste "
       << it2->get_coste()
       << endl; //para ningun operador se pone el punto
  }
}
```

Otra característica interesante de C++11 es el for basado en rangos. Con este tipo de bucle nos ahorramos los iteradores, ya que los gestionará C++ por detrás de forma transparente para nosotros:

```
for(std::vector<Nodo> const& lista : nodos_visitados)
{
  for(Nodo const& nodo : lista)
  {
    os << " Nodo  con puntos "
       << nodo.get_x()
       << " y "
       << nodo.get_y()
       << "  con coste "
       << nodo.get_coste()
       << endl; //para ningun operador se pone el punto
  }
}
```

En estos bucles también podemos usar `auto`:

```
for(auto const& lista : nodos_visitados)
{
  for(auto const& nodo : lista)
  {
    os << " Nodo  con puntos "
       << nodo.get_x()
       << " y "
       << nodo.get_y()
       << "  con coste "
       << nodo.get_coste()
       << endl; //para ningun operador se pone el punto
  }
}
```